# Symfony2: How to make form_rest(form) not to display a field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

There is something I don't like. I really hate how ugly it renderizes a date choice filed (with the three selects). I don't find the way to make those huge unstyled selects to be displayed fitting my own style (or the style of my site).

So, two possibilities (and questions):

- How and where would I change that "choice" date type to make it more beautiful?
- If not possible or if too difficult, how and where would I tell the engine for it not to display a certain field (in this case that date)?

I know I can manually display each field omitting the one I don't want to appear. But how about the opposite? i.e. telling symfony to display all of the fields but one?

Answer (score 1):

At first, Symfony allow you to choose between different widgets and formats for your date or datetime field. Those are described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget .

The options to edit the field are in the class 'YourEntityType', located in the 'ROOT/TO/YOUR/BUNDLE/Form' directory.

Example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('datefield', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'));
}
```

The two possibility you propose are also possible.

1. For the first possibility, you should check the documentation about how to custom form. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

I would say that you might create you own field type which will have date_time field as parent.

1. It is also possible to delete the field 'date'.

In your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity);
$form->remove('name of your field in the entity');
```

Or in the EntityType class :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('onefiled');
        $builder->add('datefield'); //this is the line you must delete
    }
```